# Files in Finder are greyed out when trying to upload to a website

Tags: browser, finder, osx-leopard, upload

I'm using OS X 10.5.8 and I can't upload any files to specific website (I've tried all the browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox). All files are greyed out in the Finder window that opens.

I know the site is OK, because when I tried to upload from other user on my Mac or from other computers it's working just fine. I deleted the `.plist` files, restarted the apps, but with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: So, just to be sure, it *does* work on another site? Is the upload a regular file upload through a form, or does it work by dragging and dropping? What specifically fails? Do you get an error message or does the upload not finish?

Comment: It does work on other sites, it's a regular file upload - through a form, and the problem is that all the files are greyed out - I can't even choose them...

Comment: So you can't choose anything from the *Open File…* window in Finder?

Comment: That's right, I can't choose anything.

Comment: Okay, in the future please be as specific as you can, otherwise it's hard to tell what the real problem is. Which site is it? What kind of files *should* you be able to upload?

Comment: Also what is the path of the folder / location you are looking at when the open dialog comes up?

Comment: The site is http://www.brightcove.com
The supported files are video files - .mov/.avi/.mp4/.wmv/.flv etc.
I've tried to upload files from anywhere - the desktop, the main movies folder, even from external disk, nothing worked....

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you maybe add a screenshot? Are you sure you have a file of these types e.g. on your Desktop?

Comment: I'm sure I have these types of files on my desktop, I'll attach the screenshot later

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is resetting Safari. You can do this by going to **Safari → Reset Safari...**. Make sure all the boxes are checked and click **Reset**. What site is it?

Comment: The site is http://www.brightcove.com/en/ I've tried to reset, no success.